# Getting mail room and its associated .nsf file in Lotus Domino 9.0.1

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus

Is there any way i can get mail room and its associated db mapping in lotus domino.We are using lotus domino 9.0.1 .Is it possible to get it through REST services exposed by Domino 9.0.1?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "mail room", but assuming that it is a mail-in application database, you can use the REST services to get entries from the Mail-In Databases view of the Domino Directory. I.e., something like this:

```
GET http://{host}/names.nsf/api/data/collections/name/Mail-In%20Databases&startkeys={name of your mail room application}&count=1
```

Comment: Response{
      "@href":"\/names.nsf\/api\/data\/collections\/name\/Mail-In%20Databases\/unid\/12",
    "@entryid":"33",
      "@unid":"12",
      "@noteid":"1D56",
      "@position":"2.2",
      "@read":true,
      "@siblings":5,
      "@indent":1,
      "@form":"Database",
      "$6":"Rooms",
      "$8":69,
      "$2":"BGL17-6-CYBELE\/Building17",
      "$5":"SCC-DOMINO\/abc",
      "MailFile":"Conf.nsf"
  }If i have to parse this response in my application.Can i refer "$2" and get the value .Is this the right approach or the column name will differ in the client place.

Comment: The Domino Directory is a system database. It is technically possible for anyone to modify the column names, but they should not do that. It would risk breaking many things. It looks like $2 refers to the name of the room which matches what you specified in the GET URL, $5 is the folder, and MailFile is the filename.